# How do I access the color of a specific Container?

Tags: dart, flutter

The following fragment is from an app I am playing with.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'LayoutBuilder',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('LayoutBuilder'),
        ),
      body: new LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constaint) {
          children: <Widget> [
            return new GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(child: new Center(child: new Text("data")),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.indigo, 
                                                        shape: BoxShape.circle)),
                new Container(child: ...),
                new Container(child: ...),
                new Container(child: ...),
                new Container(child: ...),
                new Container(child: ...),
                new Container(child: ...),
                new Container(child: ...),
                new Container(child: ...),
                new Container(child: ...),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Each container has a different BoxDecoration color.

At some point, say, at a user tap, I want to swap the colors of two Containers. I would like to code "children:  tiles = [" but that violates language rules. If I could, then I could access a specific Container through an index as in tiles[0], tiles[1], ....

So, how do I access the color in a specific Container?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than accessing the color of the container, I'd advise saving the colors as a member variable to the class and having the containers build from that.

In that way, you could simply setState() the order of the colors in the list (although you might have to be careful that it recognizes the list as having been changed - flutter might do a naive 'is list the same object' rather than actually checking whether its elements changed, in which case you could simply keep an integer you increment with each change).

If this is not possible, you could potentially keep a list of GlobalKeys and pass them to each of the containers (although rather than using containers you'll have to use your own StatefulWidget with the color set in it's state). However, I'd advise strongly against doing it this way.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. There is now a StatefulWidget with a State. 

When I run the app on a Samsung phone the visual components are present as expected. However, when a tile is tapped, only a debug message appears, the tile color does not change. If I examine the contents the tiles, I see that tiles that were not tapped have a color and the tile that was tapped is white. It appears that setState() is executing as expected but the rendering engine is not recognizing that one tile has changed color.